# How to check if a module is installed or a model is existed in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I want to inherit a form from another custom module without depends but It need to be check if that module is installed or model is existed before inherit it. I researched many docs but not found any solution regards so pls help me how can I do this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can know if a module is installed checking the `state` field in the `ir_module_module` table.

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 6):

Check whether the module has been installed, and is in an installed state by querying against `ir.module.module`:

```py
bokeh = self.env['ir.module.module'].search([('name', '=', 'module_name')])

if not bokeh or bokeh.state != 'installed': 
    raise UserError(_('...'))
```

Comment: The code checks whether a module in odoo has been installed by searching the module name and checking the state which is either installed or uninstalled

Answer (score 0):

To check module installed in odoo or not follow below step :

Login with Administrator access user > Click on Apps Menu from the Top Bar > You can search module with name or Apply Filter Installed

[image]